# Javascript code on last callback from deleting records one by one

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

How can I delete all records from a collection? I tried doing it as shown below, but for 1000 records there are 1000 callbacks. There should be a better way.

```
dpd.mycollection.get(function(result,error){
result.forEach(function(entry) {
    dpd.mycollection.del(entry.id,function(){});
});
})
```

I want to execute some code only after the last record is deleted. I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: Which library is this, if any? Where are the promises? Or do you want use promises, but haven't yet? In that case, google for "JavaScript promise"  and you will find plenty of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q):

```
Q.ninvoke(dpd.mycollection, "get").then(function(res) {
    return Q.all(res.map(function(entry) {
         return Q.ninvoke(dpd.mycollection, "del", entry.id);
    }));
}).then(function(dels) {
    console.log("results of all deletions", dels);
}, function(err) {
    console.error("there was an error somewhere", err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where this code is running but I'll suggest using the [**async**.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each)

```
function delete_entry (entry, callback) {
  dpd.mycollection.del(entry.id, callback);
}

async.each(entries, delete_entry, function (err) {
  console.log('finished!');
});
```

The way to do it **without any library** is to have a counter:

```
var deleted_records = 0;

entries.forEach(function (entry) {
  dpd.mycollection.del(entry.id, function () {
    deleted_records++;

    //are more records pending to be deleted?
    if (deleted_records < entries.length) return;

    //at this point deleted_records is equal to the amount of entries
    //so we can asume all records have been deleted
    console.log('finished!');
  });
});
```